# Question for deletion

Tags: discussion, status-completed, deleted-questions

Should this question be deleted

https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/7223/have-you-ever-bought-china-stock-do-you-want-to-buy-china-stock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed – it's been deleted.